# EF Core 3.1 - how to detect client-side evaluation errors using the InMemory Provider?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

After upgrading the EF Core to the 3.1 version, we starting getting runtime exceptions related to Client-side evaluations ([Client vs. Server Evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval)). We are using the [InMemory Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) to tests our EF Core code, all our tests are passing.

I would like to know if is possible to detect those exceptions in some way in the tests.

Answer (score 0):

you should have integration tests running against real integ db. i too have experienced some issues where all test passed on inmemory db but then failed when running on real db.